# Bootstrap DIV not filling 100% Height for use with background-color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I know there are a much of posts about this but I tried the solutions in each and failed. Fair warning I am not particularly good at understanding CSS (I am trying though)

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Question Form Modal</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .QuestionFormLeft {
        background-color:white;
    }
    .QuestionFormRight {
        padding-top: 0;
        background-color:#DBDDDE;
        height: 100%;

    }
    .QuestionFormRight p:first-child {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .QuestionFormRow {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #DBDDDE; 
    }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row QuestionFormRow">
    <div class="col-sm-4 QuestionFormLeft">
        <h4>Question 1 Title</h4>
        <p>Some words and description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 QuestionFormRight">
        <p>Please select a option from below:</p>
        <select>
            <option>Awesomeness</option>
            <option>Greatness</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row QuestionFormRow">
    <div class="col-sm-4 QuestionFormLeft">
        <h4>Question 2 Title</h4>
        <p>Some words and description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 QuestionFormRight">
        <p>Please select a option from below:</p>
        <select>
            <option>Awesomeness</option>
            <option>Greatness</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also here: https://jsfiddle.net/dwzndscm/

How do I get the Right DIV QuestionFormRight to do 100% height so it will fill the background in.

Note: Page Width auto sizes so the page has to be wide enough to stack left right vs top / bottom.

Sure I could do it with a table but trying to hard not to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fiddle is using v3.3.7, but the question is tagged Bootstrap 4? If you use BS4 it will automatically be full height https://www.codeply.com/go/p9n7tiJFFI thanks to flexbox.

Comment: You are absolutely right, sorry was getting confused on Bootstrap versions. I thought GA was 4 but I guess its 3. I switched to Alpha 4 and sure enough its working great. I am happy enough with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS flexbox and specifically `flex: 1` so that `.QuestionFormRight` has the ability to grow on an equal basis.  See the code snippet below for a working example.

Hope this helps.

```css
.QuestionFormLeft {
  background-color: white;
}

.QuestionFormRight {
  padding-top: 0;
  background-color: #DBDDDE;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.QuestionFormRight p:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.QuestionFormRow {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #DBDDDE;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Question Form Modal</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row QuestionFormRow">
      <div class="col-sm-4 QuestionFormLeft">
        <h4>Question 1 Title</h4>
        <p>Some words and description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 QuestionFormRight">
        <p>Please select a option from below:</p>
        <select>
            <option>Awesomeness</option>
            <option>Greatness</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row QuestionFormRow">
      <div class="col-sm-4 QuestionFormLeft">
        <h4>Question 2 Title</h4>
        <p>Some words and description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 QuestionFormRight">
        <p>Please select a option from below:</p>
        <select>
            <option>Awesomeness</option>
            <option>Greatness</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `height: 100vh` I just used it and it worked. Your jsfiddle link does not work though.